# Using fallback paths with RequireJS Optimizer

Tags: javascript, requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

My goal is to have a dependency, foo, to load from a CDN with a local fallback *and* to use RequireJS optimizer (r.js) to bundle and minify everything else.

`require(['foo'], function (foo) { /*...*/ })` calls should work without [errbacks](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#errbacks) - at least not everywhere that depends on foo, I'm cool with defining one errback in a shared location if it was possible but the global `onError` seems like it cannot be used in this manner.

The config that works without r.js:

```
require.config({
    // ...
    paths: {
        'foo': [
            '//path-to-cdn',
            'lib/local-path' // The fallback path
        ]
    }
]);
```

The optimize call in gulpfile:

```
requirejs.optimize(
{
    mainConfigFile: 'path-to-config',
    name: 'path-to-main',
    out: 'path-to-dist'
}
```

The output after I changed the foo's path to an array (instead of a single string):

> Error: paths fallback not supported in optimizer.

I've tried supplying paths as an override to the optimize call [as recommended](https://github.com/requirejs/requirejs/issues/791#issuecomment-21084122) without success:

```
requirejs.optimize(
{
    // ...
    paths: {
        'foo': [
            'https://path-to-cdn',
            'lib/local-path' // The fallback path
        ]
    }
}
```

This sounds like a basic requirement to me, can't I specify a fallback path for a module using RequireJS and its optimizer?